# Connecting vps via putty

Tags: putty, vps

i want to configure vps for some data mining project (kind of playground) but i have trouble with connecting the server through putty. I give the IP adress as host name, then in the console I  give the user and the password I received from the supplier, but I still have a message "ACCESS DENIED". Is there anything else I need to configure?

Toto

[here's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ81N.png)

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot with error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you have three way to solve issue

1. Restart SSH Services,
2. Reset your password,
3. Change your local network IP,

and the last option is to check connectivity on port 22.